# Get file from Google Drive via shared link

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm making something like online journal app, that will download "journal file" from Google Drive (via shared link) once and will update that file if it changes. Please, can anyone point me to some guides how to do it. I already tried to pin file from drive, but I don't really understand what to do next..

Comment: @noogui , yes, I found some sort of workaround. If "admin user" share file to other users, than they can select this file through file browser, and then you can easily get what i wanted.

Comment: have you tried my answer too? i used them for direct downloads of google files

Comment: @noogui ,yes, your answer works as well. Only thing was that in your way user needed to know FILE_ID (if it was several files, or if it will change), but in the rest it work perfectly fine. 
I'll chose it as right answer, because my workaround is just workaround with Android standard file picker.
Thanks, you did great job.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Downloading Files from Google Drive:**

To download a Google Drive file via link, try this (from [this tutorial](http://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/)):

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID

Just replace the FILE_ID with the original fileID found in the Drive URL.

Additonal notes:

You can download files using the [DRIVE REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_a_file)

To download files, you make an authorized HTTP GET request to the file's resource URL and include the query parameter alt=media. For example:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHESVbXTUv5mHMo3RYfmS1YJonjzzdTOFZwvyOAUVhrs
```

Downloading the file requires the user to have at least read access. Additionally, your app must be authorized with a scope that allows reading of file content. For example, an app using the drive.readonly.metadata scope would not be authorized to download the file contents. Users with edit permission may restrict downloading by read-only users by setting the viewersCanCopyContent field to true.

**Updating files in Google Drive**

Make an HTTP Request to Google Drive using PATCH. The [PATCH method](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc5789/?include_text=1) requests that a set of changes described in the request entity be applied to the resource identified by the Request- URI. Things to take note of are:

1. Parameters
2. Authorization
3. Request Body

Comment: Do I need to use DRIVE REST API if all I need is to download a file as a public shareable link?

Comment: @live-love no need for the API if the file permissions are set to anyone with the link.

Comment: @RonenRabinovici without the API, can you *programmatically* download content (ex: in a Python program) if you have shareable link?

Comment: @Patrick yes - I have a Java server that does exactly that using the following code: FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, uploadedFile);   My guess a basic https GET is just as good for small files. Large files may need something more complex. I bet python has the equivalent to Java's FileUtils.copyURLToFile.

Comment: @RonenRabinovici Thanks Ronen! Can you give an example of the url that you use?  Suppose the shareable link is https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RnlQzHf04j8N_ThuS3BtkZ-nyk6F22Hp, what will be the url?

Comment: If I use the above url in a python requests.get command, I get a file that seems to be an HTML file with javascript inside, not my plain csv file.

Comment: @Patrick , here's the url form for direct downloading a file from Drive with id `downloadUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + id; `

Comment: @RonenRabinovici . Unfortunately it does not work for me: url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1RnlQeHf04j8N_ThuS3BtkZ-nyk6F2sHp"; content = requests.get(url).content.decode('utf-8'). content is HTML and javascript.

Comment: @Patrick maybe your file is not publicly available via link? Clicking your link leads to nowhere even on a browser. Here's how to make it public: https://www.howtogeek.com/299668/how-to-create-shareable-download-links-for-files-on-google-drive/

Comment: @RonenRabinovici no no, it's just that I changed a little bit the url (because my file is not public!). I see the html as a result and not the content of the text file (a comma delimited csv file).

Comment: Im facing CORS issues using a simple get on the url