# Get Shareable link of uploaded file to google drive in android

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I uploaded an image file to Google Drive using Android code. What I want is to get the shareable link of the file I uploaded. Below is my code to upload file,

```
OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
Bitmap image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), uri);
ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapStream);
outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
        .setTitle(imgFile.getName())
        .setMimeType("image/jpeg")
        .setStarred(true).build();

// create a file in root folder
Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
        .createFile(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet, driveContents)
        .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
```

(uri is the sdcard path to my image file in above code.)

I am getting result in below callback,

```
final private ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new
    ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFileResult result) {
            if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File uploaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            }
            return;
        }
    };
```

Please help me to get the link of the file I uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37654588/get-file-from-google-drive-via-shared-link) related to your query,

> **Downloading Files from Google Drive:**
>
> To download a Google Drive file via link, try this (from [this
>   tutorial](http://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/)):
>
> https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID
>
> Just replace the FILE_ID with the original fileID found in the Drive
>   URL.

And some further reading also from the same post.

> Additonal notes:
>
> You can download files using the [DRIVE REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_a_file)
>
> To download files, you make an authorized HTTP GET request to the
>   file's resource URL and include the query parameter alt=media. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
> Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHESVbXTUv5mHMo3RYfmS1YJonjzzdTOFZwvyOAUVhrs
> ```
>
> Downloading the file requires the user to have at least read access.
>   Additionally, your app must be authorized with a scope that allows
>   reading of file content. For example, an app using the
>   drive.readonly.metadata scope would not be authorized to download the
>   file contents. Users with edit permission may restrict downloading by
>   read-only users by setting the viewersCanCopyContent field to true.